# "realloc(): invalid next size" when reallocating memory a char** pointer that is a member of a struct

Tags: c, struct, realloc

I just started learning C recently, and am having issues figuring out memory allocation. I have spent about the last 2~3 days in my extra time trying to figure this out, but have not found a solution yet. So first, I have two structs:

```
struct _list {
    // arr is an array of string arrays
    char **arr;
    // recs tracks how many records are in the list
    size_t recs;
    // arrSizes records the size of each string array in arr
    size_t *arrSizes;
};
typedef struct _list list_t;
```

and

```
struct _string {
    char *string;
    // size is used to store strlen
    size_t size;
};
typedef struct _string string_t;
```

I initialize the above structs respectively in the following ways.

**list_t**:

```
list_t *NewList() {
    list_t *List = NULL;
    List = malloc(sizeof(*List));
    if (List == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory to list structure.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    List->arr = malloc(sizeof(List->arr));
    if (List->arr == NULL) {
        free(List);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory to list array.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    List->arrSizes = malloc(sizeof(List->arrSizes));
    if (List->arr == NULL) {
        free(List);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory to size array.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    List->recs = 0;
    return List;
}
```

**string_t**:

```
// a string array read in by the program is passed with "char* record"
string_t *NewString(char *record)
{
    string_t *String = NULL;
    String = malloc(sizeof * String);
    if (String == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory to string structure.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    String->size = strlen(record) + 1;
    String->string = malloc(String->size);
    if (String->string == NULL) {
        free(String);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory to string array.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(String->string, record);
    return String;
}
```

I read lines from a file and load them into a "matching results" buffer using something like the following code. Please ignore exits and the fact that I don't have null handling after struct initialization is complete; I will add something more useful later. Also, sorry about the length. I edited quite a bit to produce the smallest example I could think of that reproduces the issue.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Check if File exists
void FileExists(FILE *FilePath) {
    if (FilePath == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: File not found.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

// Delete a string_t struct
int delString(string_t *Structure)
{
    if (Structure != NULL) {
        free(Structure->string);
        free(Structure);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Allocate memory for additional elements added to members of list_t struct
void AllocList(list_t *List, size_t StrLen)
{
    char **ArrStrArr_tmp;
    size_t *SizeArr_tmp;
    char *StrArr_tmp;

    ArrStrArr_tmp = realloc(*List->arr, sizeof(**ArrStrArr_tmp) * List->recs);
    SizeArr_tmp = realloc(List->arrSizes, sizeof(*SizeArr_tmp) * List->recs);
    StrArr_tmp = malloc(sizeof(*StrArr_tmp) * StrLen);

    if ((ArrStrArr_tmp == NULL) || (SizeArr_tmp == NULL)
        || (StrArr_tmp == NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        List->arr = ArrStrArr_tmp;
        List->arrSizes = SizeArr_tmp;
        (List->arr)[List->recs-1]= StrArr_tmp;
    }
}

// Add a record to a buffer
int AddRecord(list_t *List, char *AppendRecord)
{
    string_t *line = NewString(AppendRecord);
    List->recs++;

    AllocList(List, line->size);

    (List->arr)[List->recs - 1] = line->string;
    (List->arrSizes)[List->recs - 1] = line->size;

    delString(line);
    return 0;
}

// Sends entire string array to lowercase
void tolowerString(char *UpperString, size_t StrLen)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (int)StrLen; i++) {
        UpperString[i] = (char)tolower(UpperString[i]);
    }
}

// Attempt to match string in lines from a file; lines with matches are read into a buffer
int main()
{
    char line[80];
    int PrintedLines = 0;
    list_t *ResultList = NewList();
    char *MyString = "theme";
    char *Filename = "List.txt";
    FILE *in = fopen(Filename, "r");

    // Check if file exists
    FileExists(in);

    while (fscanf(in, "%79[^\n]\n", line) == 1)
    {
        char LookString[80];
        strcpy(LookString, line);
        LookString[strlen(LookString) - 1] = '\0';
        // send lookstring to lowercase
        tolowerString(LookString, strlen(LookString));

        // add line to buffer ResultList if it contains MyString
        if (strstr(LookString, MyString)) {
            AddRecord(ResultList, line);
            PrintedLines++;
        }
    }
    // If PrintedLines is at zero after the while statement terminates, return in abnormal state
    if (PrintedLines == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No matches found. Please check your input if you are sure there is a match.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to read the 5th matching record into my buffer, my program crashes  at this line in the AllocList function:

```
ArrStrArr_tmp = realloc(*List->arr, sizeof(**ArrStrArr_tmp) * List->recs);
```

I get the following message on the version I have posted above:

```
realloc(): invalid old size
aborted (core dumped)
```

My guess is that I'm running into an error after some default amount of memory from my initial malloc is used, but I have no clue what is actually causing this. In my actual code I'm printing all sorts of things (pointer sizes, etc.), but I still can't spot anything. What's strange is, before writing this post, I was actually seeing the error:

```
realloc(): invalid next size
aborted (core dumped)
```

But I can't reproduce it now for some reason...

I have also read that I should reallocating memory for my list_t struct whenever I add an element to one of it's members, but reallocating it actually doesn't change where or how this program crashes. In any case, I'm not sure how I should be reallocating memory for my struct. To clarify, my questions are:

1. What is causing this memory issue?
2. Should I be reallocating memory for my list struct, and how much should I be reallocating given that I'm adding an extra element to the arr and arrSizes members?

Comment: Not reading your code carefully, reallocating `*List->arr` and assigning its result to `List->arr` looks unusual.

Comment: In the function `AddRecord`, `delString(line);` is called and `line->string` will be freed there while the value is assigned to `(List->arr)[List->recs - 1]`. This looks dangerous.

Comment: What is `line` in the `main` function?

Comment: The error message is telling you that you have a memory corruption bug somewhere. (For example, in `AllocList`, if one realloc fails and the other succeeds, you leave the originals pointing to freed memory.) There are a few places that others have called out as potential problems as well.

Comment: `List->arr = malloc(sizeof(List->arr));` and `List->arrSizes = malloc(sizeof(List->arrSizes));` looks weird because they are allocating according to not size of what to point but size of pointers, but don't seem harmful because they are considered to have 0 elements and are subjects of re-allocations.

Comment: You should check if `List->arrSizes` after `malloc()` is `NULL` instead of checking `List->arr` twice.

Comment: heretomurimudamura, `*List->arr` --> is  that like `*(List->arr)` or `(*List)->arr`?  Which one do you want?

Comment: heretomurimudamura, Why -1  in `LookString[strlen(LookString) - 1] = '\0';`?  What is this line of code doing?

Comment: @MikeCAT I think in this case I probably stayed up too late reading it..thanks for your comment. As I said, (I'm sure you can tell) but I don't totally know what I'm doing yet, I've just been trying to piece together understanding by reading several sources, including on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @MikeCAT About calling ```delString```: a new ```string_t``` is initialized in every loop where I find a match, and I don't really want to keep each old struct in memory; I just want to pass its information to the list_t buffer.
```line``` in the main function is used for reading the information from a file into a buffer; I now realize that I did not explicitly define it while trying to shorten my code for this post.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica About ```*List->arr```, I was just trying to figure out how to properly dereference the struct member. Not totally sure what the correct syntax for this is. I've found a lot of different examples online, but not sure which ones are bad practice (or if I'm understanding them correctly at all).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ```LookString[strlen(LookString) - 1] = '\0';``` is from an old example I made from a book I'm using, where the code they gave was not working as it is "supposed to"; I was having trouble reading in the lines for some reason, and manually sticking '\0' on the end improved that. Each string array was initialized with 80 bytes, but actual string array length was variable (and much smaller than 79 characters).

Comment: @heretomurimudamura "and manually sticking '\0' on the end improved that" make little sense.  For `strlen(LookString)` to work, `LookString` already has a _null character_ `'\0'`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good point. I will revisit this area and do something that makes a little more sense. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the crash suggests, the line

```
    ArrStrArr_tmp = realloc(*List->arr, sizeof(**ArrStrArr_tmp) * List->recs);
```

is wrong.
This have it read an uninitialized buffer allocated via `malloc()`, whose value is indeterminate.

The intension of this line is to re-allocate the array pointed at by `List->arr`, which is an array of `char*`.

Therefore, the line should be

```
    ArrStrArr_tmp = realloc(List->arr, sizeof(*ArrStrArr_tmp) * List->recs);
```

just like the following line, which is re-allocating an array of `size_t`.

```
    SizeArr_tmp = realloc(List->arrSizes, sizeof(*SizeArr_tmp) * List->recs);
```

---

Also I found 2 more points for improvement:

Firstly, the usage of some `malloc()` in the function `NewList` are not good.
The function is creating zero-element array, so you won't need space for `List->arr` and `List->arrSizes`.
Also note that `realloc()` accepts `NULL` as the buffer to re-allocate.

```
list_t *NewList() {
    list_t *List = NULL;
    List = malloc(sizeof(*List));
    if (List == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory to list structure.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    List->arr = NULL;
    List->arrSizes = NULL;
    List->recs = 0;
    return List;
}
```

Secondly, you are copying pointer instead of string in `AddRecord`,
so you have problems of memory leak and potential use-after-free.
It seems the string should be copied:

```
    (List->arr)[List->recs - 1] = line->string;
```

should be

```
    strcpy((List->arr)[List->recs - 1], line->string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try this out later today and get back to you. Some questions:
1) In your fixed version of my ```ArrStrArr_tmp`` realloc statement, why is ```sizeof(**ArrStrArr_tmp)``` incorrect? Here I'm intending to add one more position to ```char** arr``` in my ```list_t``` struct, so I am a little surprised that ```sizeof(*ArrStrArr_tmp)``` (with only 1 pointer level) is correct.

Comment: 2) In my struct initialization statements, would it be better to just start by initializing members that will be reallocated to NULL?

Comment: 3) Is it okay for me to **not** realloc the list_t struct itself?

Comment: 1) `ArrStrArr_tmp` is an pointer for array of `char*` (representing strings). Threfore, the size for one element (obtained via `sizeof`) should be `sizeof(*ArrStrArr_tmp)`. `sizeo(**ArrStrArr_tmp)` is bad because `**ArrStrArr_tmp` is `char` and its size is typically smaller than pointers. 2) I think initializing to `NULL` is better because it will reduce. Actually you wrongly wrote the allocation size and variable to check. 3) Yes, you don't need realloc unless you want to deal with list(s) of `list_t` whose length will be dynamically changed.

Comment: I see, so by taking the size of ```**ArrStrArr_tmp```, I'm inadvertantly dereferencing the pointer and taking the size of something smaller...Thanks for all of the answers!

Comment: sorry it took so long to get back to you. Your suggestions worked perfectly. Thank you so much!